# sockets long reading data

Tags: java, android, sockets

This is my code:

```
private String receiveData(String sjson) {
        Log.i(TAG,"send request: " + sjson);
        String jstr="";
        try {
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            out.write(sjson.getBytes());
            out.flush();
            //out.close();
            Log.v(TAG,"sended data");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            char[] cbuf = new char[1];
            input.read(cbuf);                   
            String size = new String(cbuf);
            while (input.read(cbuf) != 0) {
                if((new String(cbuf)).equals("{") == true) 
                    break;
                size = size + new String(cbuf);
            }
            char[] jbuf = new char[Integer.valueOf(size)];
            input.read(jbuf);
            jstr = "{" + new String(jbuf);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"responce: " + jstr);
        return jstr;
    }

    public void connectSocket() {
        Log.v(TAG,"connecting Socket: "+URL+":"+PORT);
        try {
            s = new Socket(URL, PORT);
            Log.v(TAG,"connect Socket!");
            ERROR_CODE = 0;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            ERROR_CODE = ERROR_SOCKET_CONNECT_SUCCESSFULL;
        }
        Log.e(TAG,getErrorMsg(ERROR_CODE));
    }

    public void closeSocket() {
        Log.v(TAG,"closeSocket");
        try {
            s.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }
```

At server the answer is less than a second. At the client it passes 1 minute before reading data.

Apps stoped at `input.read(cbuf);`  waiting for answer.

Logs:

```
05-23 06:35:17.540: VERBOSE/Utilits(358): Auth: 77.221.129.100:10598
05-23 06:35:17.660: INFO/Utilits(358): send request: 0119{"data":{"password":"12345","imei":"000000000000001"},"method":"login"}
05-23 06:36:17.909: DEBUG/Utilits(358): responce: {"response":{"success":true,"user":{"id":"6","properties":{"auto":"model":"audi","color":"ffff","number":"td123r"}},"is_driver":"1"}}}
```

Why does it take so long to read an answer?

Answer (score 1):

What on earth do you expect that method to do? There are bugs in it, and it does things that it should do.

- You should specify encoding/charset when you create the InputStreamReader
- Why do you read character by character from start to "{"
- Why do you create a string for each character that you read before you hit "{"
- Why do you append strings in a loop? Use a StringBuilder if you must append.
- input.read returns an integer that says how many bytes/character that you have received
  It's never guaranteed that it will fill the buffer. So you might not get all data.
- Why aren't you closing resources?

.. and now to why it might be slow. Is the server flushing the data? If not, make sure that the server is flushing the data.

Comment: thank, I all correct. server is flushing data, in this in the problem. i noticed what when i read 1 byte, then data reading 1sec.
but then i read 2 byte, then data redind 1min.